# Como deixar responsivo diversas imagens

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

```css
section {
 font:bold;
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}

img  {
width: 233px;
height: 302px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

img:hover {
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

h2 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: -0.6;
}

p {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 2.50;

}

/*Alinhando as caixas*/

.caixa-e {

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 5%;
 transform: translate(-5%,-50%);
}

.caixa-d {

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 28%;
 transform: translate(-28%,-50%);
}

.caixa-m {

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}


.caixa-j {

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 72%;
 transform: translate(-72%,-50%);
}

.caixa-w {

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 95%;
 transform: translate(-95%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section">

<h1>Dream Team</h1>

<div class="caixa-e">


<img src="img/erian.jpg">

<h2>Erian Erik  ★ </h2> 
<p>Lider do projeto </p>
</div>

<div class="caixa-d">


<img src="img/DANI.jpg">
<h2>Danielle Saluti</h2> 
<p>Analista e Redatora</p>
</div>

<div class="caixa-m">


<img src="img/mat.jpg">
<h2>Matheus Magalhaes</h2> 
<p>Programador Java</p>
</div>

<div class="caixa-j">


<img src="img/JEAN.jpg">
<h2>Jean Braga</h2> 
<p>administrador Banco de dados</p>
</div>

<div class="caixa-w">


<img src="img/walter.jpg">
<h2>João Vitor</h2> 
<p> Auxiliar geral</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: com `widht`e `height` fixos em `px` não vai ficar responsivo, tente mudar pra percentual

Comment: O que ria responsivo pra vc? Simplesmente não deixar uma imagem encavalando na outra fazendo a largura delas diminuindo e mantendo todas na mesma linha? Ou vc quer que elas tenham sempre a mesma largura e quando não couber mais cai para linha de baixo? Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara...

Comment: Tente explicar o resultado esperado. Você só copiou e colou seu código. Fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Quero que quando diminuir a janela as imagens vão ficando uma embaixo da outra ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu css faça o seguinte:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de usar a meta tag viewport para deixar seu site responsivo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

E prefira usar medidas relativas como em % no lugar de px que são fixas.